# Create a Static Array in D that is not known at compile time

Tags: d, dynamic-arrays

How do I create a static array in D, which size is not specified at compile time?

```
immutable ulong arrayLength = getArrayLength();
ubyte[arayLength]; // <- How to do this basically
```

Comment: immutable won't work there, as you won't be able to change the contents

Comment: It would help if you explain what you mean by "static." Can you give a longer example?

Comment: @gmfawcett It cannot be modified in size, and can be used as a non-dynamic array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Short answer:* you don't. The size of static arrays is always known at compile time. If you want an array whose size is determined at runtime, then it needs to be a dynamic array.

*Longer answer:* If you want to cook up something yourself, you can use C's [`alloca`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/alloca.3.html), which can be found in core.stdc.stdlib. But I wouldn't advise messing with that sort of thing unless you really need to.

An alternative would be to have a static array that you use if the size you want is no larger than that, and if it ends up being larger, then you allocate a dynamic array. You could even create  wrapper type to handle it if you wanted to. Here's a simple one

```
struct StaticArray(T, size_t defaultLen = 10)
{
public:

    this(size_t length)
    {
        if(length <= _staticArr.length)
            _arr = _staticArr[0 .. length];
        else
            _arr = new T[](length);
    }

    inout(T)[] opSlice() inout pure nothrow
    {
        return _arr;
    }

    inout(T)[] opSlice(size_t i, size_t j) inout pure nothrow
    {
        return _arr[i .. j];
    }

    inout(T) opIndex(size_t i) inout pure nothrow
    {
        return _arr[i];
    }

    @property size_t length() @safe const pure nothrow
    {
        return _arr.length;
    }

private:

    T[defaultLen] _staticArr;
    T[] _arr;
}
```

I'm sure that that could be improved, but it gives an example of one approach to trying to avoid dynamically allocating an array when you don't know ahead of time how many elements your array is going to need.

The topic of having static arrays whose length was determined at runtime was recently [discussed in the D newsgroup](http://forum.dlang.org/post/l410kv%2420s3%241@digitalmars.com), and the language's creator, Walter Bright, argued that they're more trouble than they're worth, so I wouldn't expect to ever see such a feature in D (though we may get some sort of wrapper type in the standard library which does something similar to the example that I have here).

Comment: Will this allow using the array in functions requiring a type[x], where x is a number known at compile time?

Comment: If you slice it when passing to the function, that will work.

Comment: @JeroenBollen As Adam says, if you slice it, then you can pass it, because then you'll be using a dynamic array, and you can copy the contents of a dynamic array to a static one, but you do have to keep in mind that you can only copy as much as the static array can hold, so if x is smaller than the amount of data that you have in the dynamic array, then you won't be able to pass all of it.

Comment: IMHO, standard (ISO) C extensions, like alloca should be in a separate module, not in the `core.stdc.stdlib`. Perhaps this should be discussed on the D newsgroups... Yes, alloca() is in almost all major C run-time libraries, but still, it is not either a standard C function, nor POSIX function.